# Community Wiki Anwers badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, community-wiki

I think offering (a) badge(s) for users who choose to make their answer a Community Wiki answer would be a nice way of encouraging/rewarding those who dare to do so, even when neglecting a few/many potential points. Because we all care about our site reputation.
I post this as a feature request. Also to hear you opinions on this.

Comment: You may want to share this on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) for greater attention, since this affects all the sites, not just Astronomy. My suspicion is that people won't go for this since the SE staff are trying to phase Community Wiki out, see [this post](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/a/545/58), particularly the section after the line break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've been slowly [backing away](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) from using Community Wiki in most situations. That doesn't mean the badge is a bad idea. Rather, we'd want to find a way to make a badge that encourages the rather nuanced behavior we want to endorse. And that's not going to be easy. If you have some ideas about how to make a badge that does something other than cause people to randomly set some of their answers Community Wiki, please let me know.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of that. So I figure this would not be the way to go then.